# Is there an equivalent to commitAllowingStateLoss to Navigation Architecture Components?

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation

I'm migrating my code to the new Nav libraries, but I want some equivalent to `commitAllowingStateLoss` like there is in FragmentTransaction. Any tips?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, but you can check this https://medium.com/inloopx/demystifying-androids-commitallowingstateloss-cb9011a544cc

Comment: There is no equivalent to `commitAllowingStateLoss` - Navigation always uses `commit`. What is your use case for using `commitAllowingStateLoss`?

Comment: I'm getting an IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState. I've seen elsewhere that a workaround to this error is to use commitAllowingStateLoss(), which I previously had in my code. Not sure how to make it parallel with the Nav libraries.

Answer (score 0):

This error was occurring because I was loading a new Fragment inside of the activity, outside of the Navigation graph. I was then calling findNavController().navigate() after this, causing state loss.